# from where do we give the gas fees while deploying from vscode on a testnet?

Tags: solidity, javascript, smart-contract-wallets, visual-studio-code

just a quick question
I was following the patrick collins course on solidity with javascript and in it, we deployed a contract created on vscode using hardhat deploy on a testnet rinkeby
But since deploying on a testnet needs confirmation from metamask, to ask for the gas fees, how is it possible that we just deployed it using the terminal and no metamask pops up?
Since on the remix ide, deploying on a testnet always promts up the metamask asking us to confirm
Is there a way to integrate metamask in vscode that i probably missed?
From where did we give the gas fees while deploying on a testnet from vscode?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of metamask is to use your private key to sign/validate transactions. This can also be done in hardhat too, because you gave them a private key to deploy the contract with.

The gas fees was estimated through your RPC provider by [simulating the transaction on an EVM](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-estimategas). This number is used as the gas limit for your transactions when you make transactions on metamask or hardhat.